# Image url being treated as a page request in yii2

Tags: yii2

I am working on a project which is developed in Yii2. Today I came across a weird and funny issue of image url being treated as a page request.

When I try accessing image with url as https://www.websitename.com/images/image1.jpg, it shows me the image. And when I try accessing image with url as https://www.websitename.com/images/image1-lockdown.jpg then it shows 404 Error. On checking I found that internally the request was changed to "/site/images/image1.jpg". As we all know to access images no controller call is made.

Same issue was generated on local machine (Ubuntu 16.04). Just added "lockdown" into the name of image url.

I am using Yii2 Advanced Template. OS: For production CentOS and for development Ubuntu 16.04.
Note: I couldn't verify if the same issue exists for windows or not.

Kindly Help!

Edited: .htacess (root folder on production)

```
Options -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule admin(.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteRule gamer/(.+)?$ /gamer/web/$1 [L,PT]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess (frontend/web on production)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Looks like problem might be in your `.htaccess` can you include it?

Comment: hi michal, i have added .htaccess code

Comment: Do you have some other `.htaccess` in `/frontend/web`?

Comment: Yes, i have added that in the description. Please have a look.

Comment: Are you sure the `frontend/web/images/image1-lockdown.jpg` image exists? Try checking for typo or similar looking symbols in filename. It looks like request is handled by framework when the image should be served directly.

Comment: No such issue of file not exists or typo or anything you mentioned. When i tried putting the image in another website folder on my localhost Eg: localhost/project1/image1-lockdown.jpg then it renders. Were you able to re-produce this issue on your system?

Comment: That's rly weird, is there any other `.htaccess` in any folder on path `frontend/web/images` except those that you've already added?

Comment: That's all. Have shared everything. I would ask again.. Were you able to re-produce this issue on your system?